# Java Priority Queue Not working as intended

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

I have a `NodeWeightWrapper` wrapper to wrap `Node` object and its associated `weight`. Below is the code for wrapper. I have implemented `Comparable` and overridden `compareTo` method on `weight`, so I can use wrapper objects in a Priority Queue.

```
 public class NodeWeightWrapper implements Comparable<NodeWeightWrapper> {

private final Node node;
private int weight;

public NodeWeightWrapper(Node node, int weight) {
    this.node = node;
    this.weight = weight;
}

public Node getNode() {
    return node;
}

public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(NodeWeightWrapper o) {
    return Integer.compare(this.getWeight(), o.getWeight());
}

}
```

Adding objects to Priority Queue

```
    PriorityQueue<NodeWeightWrapper> freeNodes = new PriorityQueue<>();
    freeNodes.add(new NodeWeightWrapper(nodeA, 20));
    freeNodes.add(new NodeWeightWrapper(nodeB, 15));
    freeNodes.add(new NodeWeightWrapper(nodeC, 10));
```

Here is the problem, If I update `weight` of an object in Priority Queue as shown below. The same is not reflected next time I `poll` an object out of the Priority Queue. Which means Priority Queue sorts elements only when a new insertion takes place. So I tried removing the original wrapper object and inserted a new wrapper object with updated value but that throws ConcurrentModificationException as we are in a `foreach` loop. Any suggestion who can I make weight updation be reflected in Priority Queue.

```
for (NodeWeightWrapper nww : freeNodes) {
     if (nww.getWeight() > value) {
         nww.setWeight(value);
     }
}
```

Comment: Insert a new object, like you're trying. Just don't do it in a way that will cause a `ConcurrentModificationException` to be thrown (i.e. not inside a foreach loop).

Comment: One suggestion is to build a new priorityQueue while you are traversing the original.

Comment: You need to ensure that you don't modify the code mid-loop. Copy it into a list for later inclusion

Comment: @Kayaman But removing and adding objects will take O(logn) time. Is that an efficient way to achieve updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
PriorityQueue<NodeWeightWrapper> modified = new PriorityQueue<>();
for (NodeWeightWrapper nww : freeNodes) {
 if (nww.getWeight() > value) {
     nww.setWeight(value);
 }
 modified.add(mww)
}
```

Comment: Isn't copying objects from old Priority Queue to new Priority Queue has a time complexity of O(nlogn). Is that an efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Idea is to remove the nww from priority queue, modify it, add it back. When you do this for all n elements, you are more or less constructing a new PQ. given this scenario, it is efficient to do with complexity o(nlogn).